# Want to display records to owner only in a customer portal

Tags: customer-portal, sharing

Want to display records to owner only in a customer portal. Other users must not able to view others records

Answer (score 1):

In the Sharing Settings menu you'll find several options to control the sharing of your objects. Choose which objects you want to make private and change de **Default access** to Private.